# React.js: Can't "return false" anymore ... is there an equivalent?

Tags: events, reactjs

**Question:**

Within a React event handler, is there a convenient way to do `e.preventeDefault` and `e.stopPropagation` simultaneously (the way you used to be able to with a `return false`)?

**Background:**
React has started deprecating the use of:

```
return false;
```

inside event handlers as a means of achieving:

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/issues/78) explains that the React team is trying to solve the problem of event callbacks which `return false` incidentally (ie. without the intent to preventDefault/stopPropagation).

That makes perfect sense, and I understand the logic behind it, but ...

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

is annoyingly more difficult to remember and write than `return false`.

So, my question is: is there any convenient way to get `return false` functionality inside a React event handler?  For instance, is there some sort of `e.stopBoth()` method, or a `return React.PREVENT` constant, or any other way to get the old `return false` functionality?

Or if not, is there any way to monkey patch such a function in?

Comment: I've seen code bases ignorantly using return false too many times to think trying to do this for convenience is a good idea, also how often do you find yourself stopping propagation? Also you end up writing the func call at the start which is better practice because if there is an exception in the click handler you won't see it before the default handler moves you away to another link if you return at the bottom

Comment: I don't rely on stopPropagation that often, but because I always use it (via `return false`) I avoid a certain class of problems. Let's say I have a `<div>` with a click handler. If I add a button inside that `<div>`, and I don't `stopPropagation` as a habit, then when I forget to do it and the button is clicked it will trigger the parent's handler, causing a bug. Habitually using `stopPropagation` in all my handlers means I don't even have to think about the handlers on parent elements when I add a button (or any component).  I'd love to also not have to think when making React components.

Comment: P.S. And while there is a clear benefit (not having to think) to habitually using `return false`, there is no cost to it: if I ever actually want an element's click to "bubble up" in some specific case, then all I have to do is not `return false` in that case.

Comment: Can't you extend the Event prototype to just combine the two?

Comment: Excellent question: can I?  I apologize, but I'm new to React so I'm not sure how I'd even try.  Would it be `React.Event.prototype.myNewReturnFalseReplacement = function() { ...`?  And whether that's correct or not, if you could put the response in the form of an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: AFAIK React doesn't have this functionality. Don't mess with the Event prototype. Why not build a helper function yourself, which takes e and calls these two methods on it?

Comment: Because then I've gone from one, very short/simple line with no dependencies (`return false;`) to a more complex line that adds a dependency (`var helper = require('foo/helper'); helper.stopEvent(e);`), and requires me to add an `e` argument to every even handling function.  And I'd have to go through several hundred places in the code to find the ones that need this change :(  Ultimately I'm trying to find the least painful way to handle this (pretty massive) change the React folks are making, and it looks like an event method (ie. `return false` => `e.stop()`) will be easiest.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There isn't a definitive way of doing this, simply because it's not the behaviour the React team seems to want to encourage. There's speculation that return values from handlers could be used in some other way in future, but that sounds messy and counter-intuitive to me.

Anyway for our purposes you could:

a) Hack into the [`SyntheticEvent` stuff](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/src/renderers/dom/client/syntheticEvents), but overriding/augmenting the React internals sounds like a really bad idea. `SyntheticEvent` lets React normalize event handling.

b) Just create a simple helper function for this (hattip @octref):

```
// In some killEvent.js
module.exports = function(event) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}


// In some component file
var killEvent = require('./killEvent');

var Component = React.createClass({
    ... component implementation

    myEventHandler = function(e) {
        killEvent(e);
    }
});
```

The exact implementation would depend on what module system you're using but hopefully you get the idea. I think this is the best approach as it is extremely simple, easy to do, and expresses what you're trying to do pretty clearly.